Python Sum of array in two different variable
I have this python program
from itertools import product
import itertools
from array import array

for arr in itertools.product(("A", "B", "C"), repeat = 2): 

 print(arr)

for l in itertools.product((1, 2, 3), repeat = 2):  

 print (f"The sum is: {sum(l)}")

When I run it I get
('A', 'A')
('A', 'B')
('A', 'C')
('B', 'A')
('B', 'B')
('B', 'C')
('C', 'A')
('C', 'B')
('C', 'C')
The sum is: 2
The sum is: 3
The sum is: 4
The sum is: 3
The sum is: 4
The sum is: 5
The sum is: 4
The sum is: 5
The sum is: 6

Instead I want it to Output the Following
`('A', 'A') The sum is: 2
('A', 'B') The sum is: 3
('A', 'C') The sum is: 4
('B', 'A') The sum is: 3
('B', 'B') The sum is: 4
('B', 'C') The sum is: 5
('C', 'A') The sum is: 4
('C', 'B') The sum is: 5
('C', 'C') The sum is: 6


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read tag descriptions before using tags. From [tag:python-3.x]: "DO NOT USE UNLESS YOUR QUESTION IS FOR PYTHON 3 ONLY. Always use alongside the standard [python] tag."

You're running both loops after one another, so of course first all your letters are displayed and afterwards your calculation. You should combine the two into a single loop. Generate e.g. a list of all possibilities for both letters and numbers, then pack them together in an N-by-2 numpy array (or nested lists) and loop over that.

You need to print them concurrently (and to do so you can use zip):
from itertools import product
import itertools
from array import array


for (arr,l) in zip(itertools.product(("A", "B", "C"), repeat = 2), itertools.product((1, 2, 3), repeat = 2)):  
    print (f"{arr} The sum is: {sum(l)}")

"""
 outputs
('A', 'A') The sum is: 2
('A', 'B') The sum is: 3
('A', 'C') The sum is: 4
('B', 'A') The sum is: 3
('B', 'B') The sum is: 4
('B', 'C') The sum is: 5
('C', 'A') The sum is: 4
('C', 'B') The sum is: 5
('C', 'C') The sum is: 6
"""


You can also give the items their relevant weight/number/score and use the following:
from itertools import product

d = {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}
for arr in product(d, repeat=2):
    print(arr, f"The sum is: {sum(d[i] for i in arr)}")

output:
('A', 'A') The sum is: 2
('A', 'B') The sum is: 3
('A', 'C') The sum is: 4
('B', 'A') The sum is: 3
('B', 'B') The sum is: 4
('B', 'C') The sum is: 5
...


This is a much cleaner solution than the one suggested in the other answer. And if you already have two variables names = ("A", "B", "C") and values = (1, 2, 3) you can build the dict d using d = dict(zip(names, values))
